# Is there a way of dividing a column by the column total in presto?

Tags: presto

I'm setting up a query in presto.

I have two columns- one is the category, the other is the number.

I want to device the number column by it's total, while grouping togetherthe different categories together

[something like this is what I have in mind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8L7mi.png)

I'm fairly sure about how to this with the "with" construct, but is there a way of doing this in the same table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [window functions](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/window.html) for this purpose:

```sql
WITH data (category, number) AS (
    VALUES
        ('A', 1),
        ('A', 2),
        ('A', 3),
        ('B', 4),
        ('B', 5),
        ('B', 6)
)
SELECT category, number * 1e0 / sum(number) OVER (PARTITION BY category)
FROM data
```

which produces:

```
 category |        _col1
----------+---------------------
 A        | 0.16666666666666666
 A        |  0.3333333333333333
 A        |                 0.5
 B        | 0.26666666666666666
 B        |  0.3333333333333333
 B        |                 0.4
(6 rows)
```